# viewing a column in mysql database using php script

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to print a row from a table in mysql using a PHP script - here is the code but its not working - it shows Bad query apparently there is no issue:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

else{

echo "Connected successfully";

}


$any = "show columns from help_category";
$chk = mysqli_query($any) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
echo"<table border='3'>";
echo"<tr><td>Type</td><tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chk))

{

echo"<tr><td>{$row['Type']}</td><tr>";


}


echo"</table>";
```

Comment: this script just shows connected successfully and Bad Query after that, i cant find any bad query logs in the mysql log files. Can you confirm where shall i check them ? im using debian 9

Comment: **First** - run the query "raw" from the mysql CLI (Command Line Interface which, funnily enough, is called `mysql`!). From there you will have a meaningful (i.e. direct from the server's mouth) error message - when your SQL works from `mysql`, then "translate" it into PHP! This should be your default method of working!

Comment: i have run these queries in mysql already and they are working there. it seems that its any issue while i embed it in php.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and i found out that you have issue with your query execution on php function **mysqli_query**

mysqli_query requires two parameter first one is connection object and second one is query variable to execute a query.

Below is exact code:-

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

else{

echo "Connected successfully";

}


$any = "show columns from transaction";
$chk = mysqli_query($conn, $any) or die("Bad Query: $sql");
echo"<table border='3'>";
echo"<tr><td>Type</td><tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chk))

{

echo"<tr><td>{$row['Type']}</td><tr>";


}


echo"</table>";
```